# Dynamic height SwiftUI UIViewControllerRepresentable

Tags: swift, uitableview, swiftui

I have a UITableViewController in my SwiftUI project. The number of cells in the UITableView can be different.
1 cellHeight is 60. If I don't set a `.frame(height )` on the `Section` it will barely show one full cell. But since I don't know how many rows there will be I can't set the `.frame(height)`. And setting `minHeight`/`maxHeight` will always use the `maxHeight`...

Is there someway to count the height according to the number of cells or can I make the `TableView()` frame dynamic in some other way?

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("My UIKit Table View")) { TableView() }
                Section(header: Text("My SwiftUI View")) { ContentView() }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, CGFloat)` on your `Form{}` and then calculate the Height based on the Itemcount.

Example:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("My UIKit Table View")) { TableView() }
            Section(header: Text("My SwiftUI View")) { ContentView() }
        }
        .environment(\.defaultMinListRowHeight, 40)
        .frame(height: (50 * TableViewCount) + (50 * ContentViewCount)) + 50 * SectionHeaderCount)
    }
}
```

This has to be further customized. In my example the listRowHeight is 40, but I calculate the height with 50 so the Dividers and some Spacing is accounted for correctly.
Additionally I add 50 for the header space of the Sections.

This is kindof a hacky solution (like many in SwiftUI), but once properly Setup it works surprisingly well.